# Do read operations benefit from Bulk Execution in Cosmos DB?

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

The [Microsoft description](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/introducing-bulk-support-in-the-net-sdk/) of the Bulk Execution feature in Cosmos DB .NET SDK v3 only mentions write operations. But are read operations (maybe at least point reads) also automatically batched to increase throughput?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. bulk mode will only benefit write operations. There is no equivalent feature for read operations in Cosmos DB.

Update:

Apologies, I had incorrect information. Bulk mode will benefit both write and read operations. It does not help queries however.

Comment: Thanks, that's (disappointing but) great to know. Would be helpful to add this info to the doc.

Comment: That's good news. By read operations you mean point reads by id + partition key, right?

Comment: Correct. `ReadItemAsync` or `ReadItemStreamAsync`.