# Azure Cosmos NoSQL bulk read

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'd like to read a lot of data from NoSQL to json, flatten it and write it to a blob store as a csv.  I have my data as 1 day = 1 partition and I'd like to export a subset of data for 7 day periods.  I'm assuming a loop of 7 days, where reads are done on a single partition at a time, is fastest.   Based on this I'm looking for fast/cost efficient bulk reads from one partition with a where clause to select specific records.

Is it fastest/cheapest to:

1. query the partition for items ids that match my where clause, then
   construct an array of partition key/ids to execute
   [ReadManyItemsStreamAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.container.readmanyitemsstreamasync?view=azure-dotnet) for the final data retrieval.
2. just use [GetItemQueryStreamIterator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.container.getitemquerystreamiterator?view=azure-dotnet) with the partition and where clause to iterate over responses in a single operation
3. or some other approach

A [previous SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63992631/do-read-operations-benefit-from-bulk-execution-in-cosmos-db) suggest that the v3 sdk does take advantage of bulk operations (AllowBulkExecution) for reading but its not clear if it applies to both approaches above or if that's even the most significant factor.

Edit: Clarification - Streaming is not appropriate as these are ad hoc queries. Partition design is a separate topic and we have our reasons for this approach.

Edit: Update - we are also looking at [Synapse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/query-cosmos-db-analytical-store?tabs=openrowset-key) to help query the large datasets using serverless SQL.  Regardless the questions stands 'whats the most efficient way to retrieve query results into a text file'.  We are looking for raw NoSQL entries not just 3 attributes etc as we don't need to reshape the data on the way out.

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: This post ends up being related, even though it focuses on getting data as separate items the discussion talks about the efficiency involved: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75200619/how-to-download-many-separate-json-documents-from-cosmosdb-without-deserializing

Answer (score 1):

Stream API's are more efficient if you do not intend to deserialize the data into an object.

But if efficiency is what you seek and if your intention is to always export data to CSV written to Cosmos DB then the most efficient option is to configure change feed to do it as the data is written to your container.

Running a query on a regular basis for data in this way will consume throughput in short intervals. Depending on how much throughout you have provisioned and data you are dealing with, the query may impact performance of other operations occurring simultaneously. The cheapest and most efficient option is to stream the data out. This amortizes the throughput over a longer period of time.

One other comment too. Partitioning your data by date is an anti-pattern, in write-heavy workloads. This is because when partitioning by date, the current date is always a hot partition because all writes are going to it.

Comment: Thanks for quick response.  We are not streaming as these are adhoc queries that have different where clauses for different users (Basically asking for custom csv exports).  Agreed stream is best if we want raw json and not a concrete poco.  Thanks for the advice re hot partition.  The write operation is fairly constant and tuneable.  The read is sporadic and typically all the data will be in one day.  So the thinking is 1 day per partition to avoid cross-partition queries - will have another think.